# Retaining page number of datatable in angular.js after updating a record in angular js

Tags: angularjs

I have a datatable in my code on a view page of transaction and to update a child entry from it I have to route to child page, When I edit and update the child and route to view page again . The page number is reset to one .Please tell me how to retain the selected page number

Comment: Try maintaining the page number in querystring

Comment: @AdityaBhave .Please give me a sample code. For routing from one page to another we are using state provider. It include no page number. I am new to angular js. Please tell me how to retrive page number in angular js

Comment: Please add your sample code then I can try to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use a service to store such data that should "survive" navigation between pages.

Services are injected into the controllers and are signletons = the service object is created by angular only once and the same object lives as long as you do not leave the angular app or F5 refresh the app.

*(I did not explain how to use a service, as you can find many examples and great documentation about it)*